# Why am i always geting the command not recognized output

Tags: python, python-3.8

This are the commands the commands the host can enter

```
    elif 'command' == "custom_dir":
        conn.send(command.encode())
        print("")
        user_input = input(str("Custom Dir : "))
        conn.send(user_input.encode())
        print("")
        print("Command has been sent")
        print("")
        files = conn.recv(5000)
        files = files.decode()
        print("Custom Dir Result : ", files)
    else:
        print("")
        print("Command not recognized")
```

This is the person that gets sent this commands (Sometimes this crashes)

```
    elif 'command' == "custom_dir":
        user_input = s.recv(5000)
        user_input = user_input.decode()
        files = os.listdir(user_input)
        files = str(files)
        s.send(files.encode())
        print("")
        print("Command has been executed successfully...")
        print("")
    else:
        print("")
        print("Command not recognized")
```

Even if i change the 'command' to command i still get the same output

Comment: “always” and “sometimes” are mutually exclusive.  Which is it?  By “crashes” what do you mean? Going to need more (accurate / explicit) details here mate.

Comment: This statement `elif 'command' == "custom_dir"` does not work. The word `command` will never be equal to the word `custom_dir`

Answer (score 0):

`'command'` is a string literal. The string `'command'` will *never* be equal to the string `"custom_dir"`. It's the same as `5 == 6` - they will never be equal.

Did you mean to refer to a *variable* called `command`? In that case, write:

```
elif command == "custom_dir":
```

Comment: i still get the same output

Comment: @Grogu, what does `print(command)` _before_ the whole `if` statement output?

Comment: it sends a output to the second script

Comment: I mean, what is the value of `command` before the `if` statement?

Comment: command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()

Comment: s = socket.socket()

Comment: For the third time I'm asking for the _value_ of `command`. What data does the variable `command` refer to? If you add `print(command)`, _what_ will it print?

Comment: Okay, so the value of `command` is the string `"command recived"`, right? Is there an `elif command == "command recived":` in your code that fires when `command` has this value? Apparently not, so the `else` clauses is executed

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol with no knowledge of message boundaries. You assume that  `conn.send(user_input.encode())` will be received exactly in whole by `user_input = s.recv(5000)`, but that is not the case. It may only receive, say "Docu" instead of "Documents", or worse, only receive part of an encoded message. There are many ways to solve this problem and many existing protocols such as XMLRPC, HTTP REST, zeromq, and etc.. that offer solutions.

One option is to use b"\n" as a command terminator (and disallow "\n" in commands). Using UTF-8, you can scan for this terminator and receive in chunks. On the send side, just use `sendall(command.encode('utf-8' + b'\n')` and the recv side have a routine that splits incoming data on b'\n' before use. This is only one way of doing things, but examples are good, so...

class RecvMsgUtf8:

```
def __init__(self, skt, recvsize=5000):
    self.skt = skt
    self.recvsize = recvsize
    self.closed = False
    self.commands = []
    self.buf = []
    
def recvmsg(self):
    while True:
        # process pending commands
        if self.commands:
            command = self.commands.pop(0)
            if not command:
                self.closed = True
            else:
                return command.decode("utf-8")
        if self.closed:
            return ""
            
        # get new commands
        buf = self.skt.recv(self.recvsize)
        if not buf:
            self.commands.append(b"")
            continue # back to command process
            
        # split raw buffer into commands
        self.buf += buf
        while self.buf:
            cmd_end = self.buf.find(b"\n")
            if cmd_end == -1:
                continue # process commands and wait for data
            self.commands.append(self.buf[:cmd_end])
            self.buf = self.buf[cmd_end:]
```

To use it, higher up in your receiver code you would do

```
receiver = RecvMsgUtf8(s, 5000)
```

and in your current code, instead of s.recv, do

```
receiver.recvmsg()
```

Comment: in my case do i do: command.recvmsg(s, 5000)

Comment: No, in the example, a recv buffer size is decided when the object is created and any given command is pieced together in chunks. So you could receive megabytes for instance. This isn't efficient for large payload because of the buffered data accumulation. And if your data has newlines (say, you are receiving a text file) then you'd need an additional step that escapes the newlines to some other character sequence.